# In PHP, how do I substitute a string variable before it's evaluated?

Tags: php, string, wordpress, variables, while-loop

Is it possible to expand/substitute a variable before PHP tries to evaluate its truth value?

I'm trying to code a single Wordpress template that will execute different queries depending on which page we're on. If we're on the homepage, the query should look like this:

```
while ( $postlist->have_posts() ) : $postlist->the_post();
    // code...
```

If we're not on the homepage, the query should look like this:

```
while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
    // code...
```

So I thought I would try this:

```
$query_prefix = ( is_front_page() ) ? '$postlist->' : '';

$query_condition = $query_prefix.'have_posts()';
$query_do        = $query_prefix.'the_post()';

while ( $query_condition ): $query_do;
    // code...
```

The problem is, this is creating an infinite loop, because `$query_condition` is a string and evaluates to TRUE. It seems like PHP never 'reads' the content of the variable. I need my variable to expand itself literally, and only then offer itself for evaluation. Can anyone please tell me how how to do this?

Comment: Not that I can tell. According to var_dump() it's a string, just of varying lengths. So it will always evaluate as "set", or true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of these answers work, but to provide another alternative:

```
if(is_front_page()) {
    $callable_condition = array($postlist,'have_posts');
    $callable_do = array($postlist,'the_post');
} else {
    $callable_condition = 'have_posts';
    $callable_do = 'the_post';
}

while(call_user_func($callable_condition)) : call_user_func($callable_do);
```

Also, if you are inside an object, you can use `array($this,'method')` to call a method of your object.

Comment: It works. That is one slick solution, the most elegant that's for sure. Thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this would to use a logical or statement in your `while` condition to loop based on different objects depending on the result of `is_front_page()`, and then an `if` statement to control the call to `the_post()` as well.

```
// loop while the front page and $postlist OR not the front page and not $postlist
while ( (is_front_page() && $postlist->have_posts() ) || ( !is_front_page() && have_posts() ) ): 
    // use $postlist if on the front page
    if ( is_front_page() && !empty($postlist) ){
        $postlist->the_post(); 
    } else { 
        the_post();
    }
    // the rest of your code
endwhile;
```

Comment: you my friend are a genius! It worked. I never would have figured that out on my own. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

May be such example could possible help you. This is about using [variables of variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
class A {
    public function foo(){
        echo "foo" ;
    }
}

$a = new A() ;

$obj = 'a' ;
$method = "foo" ;


${$obj}->$method() ; //Will echo "foo"
```

Comment: The problem is that the OP wants to be able to call `$object->function()` as well as `function()`, there is no object instance on one.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the_title for determining the page.

```
$isHomePage = false;
if(the_title( '', '', FALSE ) == "Home")
{
    $isHomePage = true;
}
```

Then i use $isHomePage as a flag for anything else I need later in the page.  This can be changed to look for any page you want to single out.  It can get hairy if you have long page names though, so there is that.

Comment: You can do pretty much the same thing with the built in `is_front_page()` and `is_home_page()` functions... the question is about using a different WP_query based on the result.